# asp .Net Drop Down list returning first value the first time

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hello Im trying to remove a value from a List when it is selected in a Drop Down list but the first time i call Button1_Click1 it always removes the first index(in this case a) i have no idea what is going on

```
List<String> Alph = new List<String>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((List<String>)Session["Alpha"] != null)
    {
        Alph = (List<String>)Session["Alpha"];
    }
    else
    {
        fillAlpha();
    }


}
public void fillAlpha()
{
    Alph = new List<String>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

    Alph.Sort();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = Alph;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.Text;
    Alph.RemoveAt(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = Alph;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    Session["Alpha"] = Alph;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `if(!IsPostBack)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page_Load` is invoked on *every* post-back, and it's invoked *before* the click handler.  So when you do this:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = Alph;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

You're clobbering `DropDownList1` and re-populating it.  Then when you examine it:

```
Label1.Text = DropDownList1.Text;
Alph.RemoveAt(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
```

It's going to show you the default values, which means whatever is the first value in the data source to which it's bound.

You can prevent this by using a conditional to only populate it on an initial page load instead of post-back:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = Alph;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly and i see what i did wrong!